Can not create instance of viewModel in Compose Multiplatform Desktop App
I am just playing with compose multiplatform and injecting viewModel using Koin. Here are my koin Initialization in common Module:
fun initKoin(config: KoinAppDeclaration? = null) {
    startKoin {
        config?.invoke(this)
        modules(
            sharedModule,
            platformModule
        )
    }
}

expect val platformModule: Module

val sharedModule = module {
    singleOf(::DataRepositoryImpl).bind<DataRepository>()
    viewModelOf(::HomeViewModel)
}

My actual implementation are like this in specific platform:
actual val platformModule = module {
    single { createHttpClient(OkHttp.create()) }
}

My app runs fine in Android platform. But when I try to run it in desktop it doesnt start and gives an error dialog saying that "Can not create instance of Viewmodel..". So far I found out that it only happens when I am using any coroutinescope in the viewmodel. If I just use a plain viewmodel the app runs perfectly.
Please help!

I have finally fixed my issue, I needed to add the swing library to make Dispatchers.main() work in desktop variant. I just added this:
implementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.swing)

and my version catalog file I have added
kotlinx-coroutines-swing = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-swing", version.ref = "kotlinxCoroutinesSwing" }

